Implemented SSR in Angular 17 to dynamically update Meta tags & have a URL (http://example.com/home/add-job?id=4) with Query Params
When navigating to above mentioned url, the meta tags are not updating. If I navigate to URL Without Query Params (http://example.com/home/add-job) the meta tags gets updated.
Meta tags in index.html
`<meta
    property="og:url"
    content="https://example.com/"
  >
  <meta
    property="og:type"
    content="website"
  >
  <meta
    property="og:title"
    content="Custop App Title"
  >
  <meta
    property="og:description"
    content="Custom App Description"
  >
  <meta
    property="og:image"
    content="https://www.myhealthunlimited.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/300x200.png"
  >`

I am updating meta tags on ngOnInit using the Meta proviced by @angular/platform-browser as:
Updating Meta tags in ngOnInit
 ` const image = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1712375713833-909f9679cdba?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D'
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: https://example.com/add-job` })
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'job Type 1' })
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: 'job App Title 1' })
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: 'job App description 1' })
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: image })`

I was using Client Side Rendering in Angular 17 to update tags which were not working. After some research i came to know that i need to implement SSR in angular and implemented SSR and meta tags are updating in URL which have no Queryparams

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a working stackblitz, here is a blank stackblitz for you to try stackblitz do replicate the issue and share back, also update the necessary code in the question also!
